# Compiling a swift script into an executable

Tags: swift, macos

I have a working swift script that I want to compile as an executable.

When I execute

```
swiftc create-event-in-calendar.swift -F /System/Library/Frameworks -o create-event-in-calendar
```

I get all sorts or compile errors like

```
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h"
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:10: note: in file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:
#include <CoreGraphics/CGBase.h>
```

What do I need to do to compile the swift script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty simple. Add xcrun -sdk macosx at the start of the command line.

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc create-event-in-calendar.swift -o create-event-in-calendar
```